# Get info from current webpage in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I am member of a website and want to grab some info from the current open window in Chrome. That is, if I am looking a persons profile in Chrome, I want my C# program to be able to get the source code of that website so I can retrieve birthday, location, etc from it. Is there a way to do this?

I guess a solution is to incorporate the webbrowser control in a winforms project and use that instead of chrome. but it would be nicer if I could just use Chrome as I normally do and then when I switch to my C# program it copies the source code and parses whatever info in it that I find relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the C# version of [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for automating your browser. It's mainly designed for testing, but it should help you solving your problem. It comes with a [driver for Google Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list).